# When is the value assigned as an argument passed into a setState function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

Am trying to understand a scenario where you pass in a value to an inline click function handler in a React component.

In a scenario where user data is being mapped over e.g. a list of users which returns a list of names and a button to remove that users name, the removeItem function is passed in an id, I was wondering does this function get the value of that id as it is being mapped? so for instance if you had 100 users then there would be 100 names, 100 buttons and 100 removeItem functions created each of which has a different id associated to them? or is it just a single removeItem function which dynamically is passed an id value somehow?

```
return (
<div key="id">
  <h1>{name}</h1>
  <button onClick={() => removeItem(id)>remove</button>
</div>
)
```

Comment: There would be 100 inline functions created, but only one `removeItem` function that they each call. Hard to say much more without a complete example. `id` would have to be coming from the `map` param somehow

Comment: A 100 inline functions but only one removeItem.

Comment: @BrianThompson yes the id is coming from the map, so there would be 100 inline functions, each of which captures the id as its passed in? ok thats good to know. Is that the same reason then that when you use a setTimeout with your setState, all the functions keep the same value unless you access the previousState value?

Comment: Yes, its called a [`closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).